# Google Assistant: Search screen is not offered anymore

Tags: screen, screenshots, google-assistant

Until a few days back, whenever I opened Google Assistant as "overlay" while having open another app, the assistant always offered something saying "What's on my screen?".

When clicking, it send the current screenshot directly to Google Lens. Behaviour is the same as if I'd do a screenshot and share it with Google Lens - just without the extra overhead of doing it manually.

Looked like this:

[image]

All of a sudden, this behaviour changed / stopped.
Whenever I open the assistant, it only says "How can I help?".

As I was using the screen recognition functionality VERY often because I read stuff in apps in foreign languages and could directly translate them on screen - it's really bad for me.

Do you know how to re-enable that feature?
I did NO change to my account like Web/Browsing-History or similarly, in case that matters!?

I already tried to tell Assistant "What's on my screen", or "Search my screen" in case they just removed the permanent button... But that doesn't call the function.

I already found the option to allow access to "Screen context" within the Assistant options, it's all enabled:

[image]